# Tomcat 6 and JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: jquery, jsessionid

I hav java webapp. I am using Jquery and each Jquery maintain `jsessionID` so i want to disable the `JsessionID` of every Jquery. The following line show that js request apended with `JsessionID`

```
...../scripts/jquery.client.js;jsessionid=0097D32AFBDED3F6F99DDBFB237DF4CF
```

Comment: jsessionID is the way your server tracks your current session, most probably because you have disabled cookies in your browser. So disabling the session on the relevant JSP page may be help to remove this id from the URLs in the page.

Comment: The jessionId is generated because the JsessionID cookie is not getting generated for some reason . These are used to maintain the user sessions . response.encodeUrl attaches this .

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge Thanks but..actually i hav not enable the session in the jsp..it has being configr from xml...